# Not understanding the C format specifiers when using fscanf()

Tags: c, c99, stdio, format-specifiers, cstdio

So I am reading a text file in this format:

```
ABC 51.555 31.555
DEF 23.445 45.345
```

I am trying to use fscanf() to parse the data, because this file could grow or shrink it needs to be dynamic in the way it loads hence why i used malloc and i also want to store it in the struct below. I think the issue is with a space or even possible not writing the whole format specifier right. Here is my code.

```
typedef struct data
{
    char name[4];
    char lat[7];
    char lng[7];
}coords;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ////////////CREATES FILE POINTER/////////
    FILE* fp;
    ///////////CREATES MALLOC POINTER TO STORE STRUCTS/////////////
    coords* cp;
    //////////OPENS FILE//////////
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    /////////GET THE TOTAL AMMOUNT OF LINES IN THE FILE/////////
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    //////SKIPS FIRST LINE//////////
    while(fgetc(fp) != (int)'\n')
    {};

    /////////ASSIGNS MEMORY THE SIZE OF THE FILE TO //////////
    cp = malloc(sizeof(coords) * size);

    //////////READS FILE AND STORES DATA///////
    fscanf(fp,"%s[^ ] %s[^ ] %s[^\n]", cp->name, cp->lat, cp->lng);

    printf("%s\n%lf\n%lf\n", cp->name, cp->lat, cp->lng);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And yes I am aware I did not include the header files but I have got the right ones stdlib and stdio

UPDATE 1:
I have tried both replies and I get this on my screen:

```
ABC51.555
0.000000
0.000000
```

How come the 51.555 has not gone to the next item in the struct?
Thanks

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////UPDATE 2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Okay I have modified my code to do the following.

```
typedef struct data
{
    char name[4];
    char lat[6];
    char lng[6];
}coords;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ////////////CREATES FILE POINTER/////////
    FILE* fp;
    ///////////CREATES MALLOC POINTER TO STORE STRUCTS/////////////
    coords* cp;
    //////////OPENS FILE//////////
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    /////////GET THE TOTAL SIZE OF THE FILE/////////
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
    long lines = -1;
    rewind(fp);
    //////GETS TOTAL AMMOUNT OF LINES/////////
    char c;
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
         if(c == '\n')
         {
            lines++;
         }
    }
    rewind(fp);
    ////////////SKIPS FIRST LINE//////////
    while(fgetc(fp) != (int)'\n')
    {};
    /////////ASSIGNS MEMORY THE SIZE OF THE FILE TO //////////
    cp = malloc(sizeof(coords) * size);

    //////////READS FILE AND STORES DATA///////
    printf("Lines of text read: %d\n", lines);
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s[^\n]", cp[0].name, cp[0].lat, cp[0].lng);
    printf("%s\n", cp[0].name);


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Now when i try to print cp[0].name; I get the whole of the first line with no space in, like this.

```
 ABC51.55531.555
```

If i got print cp[0].lat; I get this.

```
 51.55531.555
```

And when i print cp[0].lng; I get this.

```
 31.555
```

Which is the only correct one, I can not understand this behaviour. Why is it behaving like this? all the posts suggest (As i first thought) that each %s in fscanf would put it in to its own variable not concatenate them. Not mater if i use the dot notation or the direct -> it still has the same result.
Thanks :)

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%s[^ ] %s[^ ] %s[^\n]"` --> `fscanf(fp," %3[^ ] %6[^ ] %6[^\n]"`

Comment: `fscanf(fp," %3s %6s %6s",...` , `printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",...`

Comment: ... use loop .. and use `cp[index].name`

Comment: Note: long usual ranges -180 to 180, lat -90 to 90, suggest bigger lat[]/lng[]

Comment: I made and update to the text

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27436454/2410359) is a good answer to your post, but code really should change `typedef struct data { char name[4]; float lat, lng } coords; ... if (fscanf(fp, "%3s%f%f", cp->name, &cp->lat, &cp->lng) == 3) Success();`

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `"%s[^`... attempts to read a whitspace delimited string, followed by the character `[` and then the character `^`.  Since the string will always end at whitespace, the next character will always be whitespace, which won't match the `[`, and none of the rest of the format specifier will match.

- ALWAYS check the return value of `fscanf` to make sure you read all the things you thing you did.  If the return value is wrong, give a diagnostic.
- ALWAYS use field size limits when reading into fixed size string arrays.

So in your case what you want is:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%3s%6s%6s", cp->name, cp->lat, cp->lng) != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect data in input file, exiting!\n");
    abort(); }
```

Comment: Note: OP is incorrectly using `printf("%s\n%lf\n%lf\n", cp->name, cp->lat, cp->lng);` to print strings.  Suspect OP should use 2 `float`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you want to use the space delimiter [^ ]. fscanf already parses the string on whitespace as default. Try this and see if the string is correctly parsed:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s[^\n]", cp->name, cp->lat, cp-lng);
```

output should result in:

```
cp->name ---- ABC
cp->lat ----- 51.555
cp->lng ----- 31.555
```